# How to get value from another row in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, lag, window-functions

I have a sql query like the following:

```
    select 

    ,c.customer_leg1
,d.mid
        ,c.previous_customer_leg1  
        ,c.creation_date
    ,c.end_date
    ,c.cid

    from table1 c

    JOIN table2 d
    ON c.cid = d.cid
    where c.cid = '1234'
```

which gives the below output:

```
customer_leg1 | previous_customer_leg1 | creation_data | end_date | cid
4092          | 1888                   | 05/06/17      | 05/07/17 | 735
8915          | 4092                   | 05/06/17      | 05/08/17 | 735
```

I want to add a new column such that for each `customer_leg1` where ever we find that in `previous_customer_leg1` it should put that row's `"end_date"` in that column.

For eg: in row 1 of the above output `customer_leg1` is `4092` and this is found in row 2 in the `previous_customer_leg1`, so in row 1, this `new_column` should have `05/08/17` in it. And for those, where the customer_leg1 doesn't match in previous_customer_leg1, it should be NULL. I think I could maybe use partition and lag function for this, but I'm not very clear on those. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are not close at all. Why do you think you need `lag()` and `partition`? What you do need is a self-join, not an analytical function. It is best to just state your problem (as you did); do not include HOW to solve it in your problem statement. (You didn't, you just give that impression by the title you gave.)

Comment: The query you posted doesn't make much sense. All the columns you select are from `table1` and the `where` conditions are also all based on the same table, why do you join to `table2`?

Comment: because the actual query is really huge and this is just a gist of what I want

Comment: @Arman - What is the criteria for order of data. I mean what determines that the 2 given rows will come is same order in output?

Comment: There is no criteria for order of the rows.

Comment: The how do you say that `customer_leg1` `4092`  is row1 and `8915` is row2? It cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only showing "the gist" of what you want, perhaps "the gist" of one possible solution is like this:

Add to your "really huge" query another join:

```
select .....
     , c1.end_date as new_column
from   table1 c join table2 d   on c.cid = d.cid
                join talbe1 c1  on c.cid           = c1.cid 
                               and c.customer_leg1 = c1.previous_customer_leg1
..................
```

Comment: why are you joining it on c.cid = c1.cid as well?

Comment: I assumed that cid may be the primary key of your table, and customer_leg1 (etc) is just an attribute, which may appear more than once in your table. If so, then you don't want to relate customer_leg1 from one cid to the previous_customer_leg1 from another cid. Of course, my assumption may be wrong, but keep in mind it is only the gist of an even more huge query than your original one. If you want a more careful and detailed answer, you will need to ask a more careful and detailed question.

Comment: On doing that I'm getting "column ambiguously defined" error

Answer (score 0):

As I asked in comments, what are the columns on which you will make sure that your `next row` is displayed correctly, as you cannot guarantee that your output will always be in same order. So assuming that your column for `order` is `creation_date`, and you want this to be done on a `partition` of `c.cid`, you can add something like below to your `select` statement to derive this new column, without disturbing the rest of the query.

Disclaimer: If the columns for `partition` and `order` are not the same, then this will not work. Please change the columns. But the concept of **reading next row for a column and if matched, then display another column from next row** is below.

```
,CASE
    WHEN lead (c.previous_customer_leg1,1) 
            over (partition BY c.cid  ORDER BY c.creation_date) 
         = c.customer_leg1 
    THEN lead (c.end_date,1) over (partition BY c.cid ORDER BY c.creation_date)
END AS new_column
```